# Summing up to a value in a loop

Tags: matlab

Hoping that there's a relatively simple way to do this and it's just me being stupid. 
I'm trying to find a combination of boxes (size) that will fit into a bigger box of a certain capacity (boxSize). Within the code (below), I've put it as geq at the moment, which is clearly no good seeing as generally the values are bigger than the carrying capacity of the box.

```
boxSize = 9;
size = [5 2 3 7 2 3 5 10 6 4]; % Box size
Nos = [50 20 300 78 22 34 55 120 643 442]; % No things in box

tmpMat = zeros(length(size),2); % Box size and number in there need to be linked
tmpMat(:,1)=size;
tmpMat(:,2)=Nos;

Order = tmpMat(randperm(length(tmpMat)),:); % Randomly sort

boxVector = [];

while(~isempty(Order)>0)                     % Determine which contributes to box
    sumMyBox=cumsum(Order);  
    sum2=find(sumMyBox(:,1)>=boxSize,1,'first');   % ISSUE here with geq 
    Used=Order(1:sum2,1);
    box = sumMyBox(sum2,:);
    boxVector = [boxVector; box];
    Order=Order((sum2+1):end,:);
end
```

The problem with simply making this leq is that it just takes the one value since 2 is < 10 (for example), whereas what I'm looking for is to sum the numbers up and take the value as close to boxSize as possible. Any suggestions? All coding is in Matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a task for the Hungarian algorithm? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11609-hungarian-algorithm

Comment: `<=boxSize, 1, 'last'`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

```
sum2=find(sumMyBox(:,1)>boxSize,1,'first') - 1;
```

Find the overflow point and backup by one.

In your current test case, if the size 10 box is first in the list, the answer comes back none. I may not fully understand your task, but it seems like you might want to compute all possible combinations of boxes. Or perhaps, sort them largest to smallest and take the largest box that fits, something like that. Hopefully I just don't fully understand the task you are trying to solve.